# How Lebesgue sigma algebra is different from outer regularity.

Tags: lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Give an example of  a non-Lebesgue measurable set $A$, such that there exist an open set $O$,  $A\subseteq O$ and $m_*(O)\leq m*(A)+\epsilon $ but $m_*(O\backslash A)>\epsilon $?

This question arise because outer regularity doesn't implies Lebesgue measurable , so I want to look at example where it fails. I haven't find any on my own.please help.

Ps. I want to see difference between outer regularity and Lebesgue measure. As it is mentioned in comments,  concrete examples are harder to find, it's enough for me to understand difference between regularity and Lebesgue measure intuitively.

Def: A set is $E$ measurable  if there exists an open set $O$ such that $E\subseteq O, m_*(O\backslash E)<\epsilon $

Theorem: Outer regularity (without proof) let $E\subset \mathbb R^n$, then $m_*(E)=inf\{m_*(O)|O \text{ is open},E\subset O\}$

Comment: Is that a definition of measurability or of outer regularity? (Also Lebesgue nonmeasurable sets cannot really be "explicitly" constructed at all, in a certain sense...constructing one necessarily requires some nonconstructive axiom, albeit not necessarily one as strong as the axiom of choice.)

Comment: Concrete examples of non-Lebesgue measurable sets are hard to come by.

Comment: @lan,@Umberto p. Is there a way I can see the difference between how definition of measurable set I  given above is different from outer regularity.

Comment: I edited the question,

Answer (score 2):

> Give an example of a non-Lebesgue measurable set A, such that there exist an open set O, A⊆O and m∗(O)≤m∗(A)+ϵ but m∗(O∖A)>ϵ?

Just consider any non-measurable set $V\subset [0,1]$. From the definition of the non-measurable set, there exists $\epsilon>0$ for any open set $O\supset V$, $m^\ast(O\backslash V)\geq \epsilon$. Of course by the definition of the outer measure $m^\ast(O)\leq m^\ast(V)+\epsilon$ is satisfied.

The answer to the question is trivial from the definitions. I think you better lookup the construction (which uses non-constructive axiom in the end) of the non-measurable set. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)

> I want to see difference between outer regularity and Lebesgue measure. As it is mentioned in comments, concrete examples are harder to find, it's enough for me to understand difference between regularity and Lebesgue measure intuitively.

Loosely speaking, the exterior measure $m^\ast(E)$ assigns to **any** $E\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ a first notion of size; as the name indicates, attempts to describe the volume of a set $E$ by approximating it from the outside (from Elias M.Stein, Rami Shakarchi; Real Analysis).

On the other hand, Lebesgue measure inherits all the features of the exterior measure, and furthermore have more desirable properties such as if $E_1,E_2,\cdots$ are disjoint measurable sets and $E=\cup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$ then $$m(E)=\sum_jm(E_j)\quad\text{(countable additivity)}.$$This is not generally satisfied in the outer measure (yet, it is hard to construct a counterexample).

Also, some intuitive explanation of the measurable set is, if $E$ is measurable then its outer measure and inner measure coincide : $m^\ast(E)=m_\ast(E)$, i.e. approximating volume of $E$ from the outside and from the inside is same.

Comment: I think you're using both $A$ and $V$ to refer to the same set which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Ian Ohh.. yes. Thank you!

Comment: I made some style edits, you are free to revert them if you don't like them. Also +1.

Comment: @Ian I couldn’t edit since I cannot use PC now. Very nice, thank you!